# Meanwell charger won't respond to I2C from ESP32 board

Tags: arduino, i2c, esp32

I'm trying to communicate between an ESP32 based PCB and a Meanwell battery charger using I2C (technically PMBUS). I also have a programmer device sold by Meanwell specifically for communicating with their charger, so I have the luxury of a known working setup for comparison. When the programmer initiates communication with the charger, I get this trace:
[image]
I can clearly see the start condition, the address (0x47), the write bit, and the acknowledgement by the charger.
When I attempt to do the same with the ESP32, I get this trace:
[image]
I can still see the start, address, and write bit, and it almost seems like the charger is trying to acknowledge. But the data line goes high in the middle of a clock cycle, which isn't permitted (right?).
I can see some other differences between the two traces:

- The programmer gives an extra long pause between the start condition and the next clock pulse, where the ESP32 does not. I haven't figured out a good way to replicate this on the ESP32, since the I2C is implemented in hardware. I tried bit-banging it, but that didn't tell me much since it's significantly slower. At any rate, that extra delay shouldn't make a difference, at least according to my limited knowledge of I2C.
- The internal pull-ups in the programmer pull the lines high much more gently than my board. I'm using a level translator between the ESP32 at 3.3V and the charger at 5V (part number TXS0104EPWR). The pull-ups in the level translator are 10k, but the datasheet says "The output one-shots detect rising edges on the A or B ports. During a rising edge, the one-shot turns on the PMOS transistors (T1, T2) for a short duration which speeds up the low-to-high transition". So the hard pull-up is expected behavior.

Finally, for what its worth, here's some minimal code for what I'm doing:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <Wire.h>

const int I2C_SDA = 4;
const int I2C_SCL = 5;
const byte SLAVE_ADDRESS = 0x47;

void setup()
{
  Wire.begin(I2C_SDA, I2C_SCL);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(3000);
}

void loop()
{
  Wire.beginTransmission(SLAVE_ADDRESS);
  int status = Wire.endTransmission(true);
  switch (status)
  {
  case 0:
    Serial.println("success"); break;
  case 1:
    Serial.println("data too long to fit in transmit buffer"); break;
  case 2:
    Serial.println("received NACK on transmit of address"); break;
  case 3:
    Serial.println("received NACK on transmit of data"); break;
  case 4:
    Serial.println("other error"); break;
  case 5:
    Serial.println("timeout"); break;
  }
  delay(5000);
}
```

Any ideas about what is going wrong are appreciated!

Comment: If the MCU pins are driven in push-pull, it may explain the problem. Also if TXS0104 rise time accelerator triggers and pushes high, then that is a problem too. Can you post further code and schematics, and in which environment the TXS0104 is (how much wiring, stray capacitance, etc)?